# JQuery method does not work on cached children objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

In JQuery, we can cache almost any objects returned by a selector, and in my case, I cache the children (`<tr>`s) of a selected element (`<tbody>` in a table) in a variable called `rows`.

I then call JQuery methods on this `rows`, which manipulate individual rows. For example, if there are 5 rows in total and I want to swap the first and the last row:

```
rows.eq(4).after(row1);
rows.eq(0).before(row5);
```

However, this does not work. The first row gets to the bottom but the bottom row does not get to the top.

What does it work is to get a fresh copy of the children on each manipulation. For comparision, please see: http://jsfiddle.net/QNS5G/

What is causing problems for the cached approach here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you change the row order in the DOM, the order in the jQuery object does not change.

So `t1_rows.eq(4).after(t1_row1);` moves the first row to the bottom (row 1 goes *after* the fifth row in the jQuery object). Then `t1_rows.eq(0).before(t1_row5);` tries to place the last row *before* row 1. Since it's already there, you don't see any changes.

Perhaps you are thinking `el.after(something)` places `el` after `something`, but it's the other way around, it actually places `something` after `el`.

Comment: "After you change the row order in the DOM, the order in the jQuery object does not change." that is the key! So does it mean that if we want to manipulate the order of the rows in the DOM continuously, we need to always get a fresh copy of the rows on every manipulation? i.e. calling `.children()`?

Comment: You can also check the current index in the DOM with `.index`, e.g. `t1_row1.index()`.

Answer (score 1):

Let me translate your code into english.

1. First, take row 1 and insert it after row 5
2. Then, take row 5 and insert it before row 1

The second operation does nothing because row1 has moved to the bottom of the list.  It's *already* right before row5.

Answer (score 0):

```
var tbody = $(document.getElementById('t1_parent')),
    first_row = tbody.find('tr:eq(0)'),
    last_row = tbody.find('tr:eq(4)');

last_row.prependTo(tbody);
first_row.appendTo(tbody);
```

**EDIT:**

Never mind. Another solution was found.

Comment: consider adding some text comments to explain a little what's going on. Avoid code only answers.